# Download only part of Database reference in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat app as part of my Android app that stores all messages in a chat room under a Firebase database reference that carries the ID number for that room. As it stands, the RecyclerView that holds the messages in the chat Activity downloads all messages in that room whenever the user enters it, consuming a potentially unwieldy amount of data. How should I go about making it only download the X most recent messages and download X more if the user scrolls to top?

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ChatRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "ChatRecyclerViewAdapter";
private String mRoomID;
private Context mContext;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ArrayList<Message> messageList;



private ChildEventListener mListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        // Convert data snapshot from Database into a Message Object

        Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);


        // Add it to an arrayList of Messages
        messageList.add(message);

        // Notice Changes
        notifyItemInserted(messageList.size());

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
};

public ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mMessage, ArrayList<String> mAuthor, String mRoomID, DatabaseReference reference) {

    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mRoomID = mRoomID;
    messageList = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabaseReference = reference.child(mRoomID+"_messages");
    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mListener);

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    //This method loads layout(fields) of ViewHolder

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_msg_row,parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // This method fills fields with data for each list item

    Log.d(TAG,"onBindViewHolder called");

    Message message = messageList.get(position);

    holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
    holder.author.setText(message.getAuthor()+":");


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messageList.size();
}

//Viewholder stores the information about the layout and content of each list item, and serves as a template for each item of a RecyclerView


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView author;
    TextView message;
    RelativeLayout singleMessageContainer;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        author = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatAuthor);
        message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatMessage);
        singleMessageContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);

    }
}

void cleanup() {

    mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mListener);
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to read up on how to do queries with Realtime Database.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the messages are stored chronologically already (e.g. if you use `push()` to add them), you can order the messages by their key and get the most recent ones with:

```
mDatabaseReference = reference.child(mRoomID+"_messages");
Query recentMessages = mDatabaseReference.orderByKey().limitToLast(10);
recentMessages.addChildEventListener(mListener);
```

As Doug commented, please check the [Firebase documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) for more options

Comment: Thank you so much. And will do.